# RadioButton Template displays extra lines on some items, but not all

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

The template that I'm trying to create is displaying unwanted lines on some items. I cannot figure out why.
This is the control template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton" x:Key="SidebarItem">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#312B57"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Border Background="#312b57">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="25 0 0 0">
            <Border Height="20" x:Name="TopContainer" >
                <Border x:Name="Top" Background="#312B57" Padding="0"></Border>
            </Border>
            <Border x:Name="Middle" CornerRadius="10 0 0 10" Padding="15 8" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <Border Height="20" x:Name="BottomContainer" Padding="0">
                <Border x:Name="Bottom" Background="#312B57" Padding="0" ></Border>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Middle" Property="Background" Value="#fff"></Setter>
            <Setter TargetName="TopContainer" Property="Background" Value="#fff"></Setter>
            <Setter TargetName="BottomContainer" Property="Background" Value="#fff"></Setter>
            <Setter TargetName="Top" Property="CornerRadius" Value=" 0 0 25 0"></Setter>
            <Setter TargetName="TextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="#312B57"></Setter>
            <Setter TargetName="Bottom" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0 25 0 0"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="TextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="#fff"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The implementation:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Sidebar" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0 25" BorderBrush="Transparent" Padding="0 10 0 0" ItemsSource="{x:Static viewModels:SidebarContent.Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:SidebarItem}">
            <RadioButton GroupName="Sidebar" Template="{StaticResource SidebarItem}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding DisplayName}"></RadioButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And the issue:
[image: Templated RadioButton with thin bright lines above and below.]
The Correct:
[image: Templated RadioButtons.]

Can someone please tell me why I am getting the extra line on some of the list items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lines are rendering artifacts, you can get rid off the effect with [`SnapToDevicePixels`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels?view=windowsdesktop-5.0):

> You can set this property to `true` on your root element to enable pixel snap rendering throughout the UI. For devices operating at greater than 96 dots per inch (dpi), pixel snap rendering **can minimize anti-aliasing visual artifacts in the vicinity of single-unit solid lines**.

Set this property to `true` on the parent `Border` element in your control template, it will apply to all child elements, since it is inherited.

> [...] only the outermost element in a subtree needs to specify `SnapsToDevicePixels` as `true`, and all child elements of that subtree will then report `SnapsToDevicePixels` as true and will have the `SnapsToDevicePixels` visual effect.

```
<Border Background="#312b57" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="25 0 0 0">
      <Border Height="20" x:Name="TopContainer" >
         <Border x:Name="Top" Background="#312B57" Padding="0"></Border>
      </Border>
      <Border x:Name="Middle" CornerRadius="10 0 0 10" Padding="15 8" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
         <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"></TextBlock>
      </Border>
      <Border Height="20" x:Name="BottomContainer" Padding="0">
         <Border x:Name="Bottom" Background="#312B57" Padding="0" ></Border>
      </Border>
   </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Alternatively, you could set the [`UseLayoutRounding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UseLayoutRounding);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-5.0) property to `true` (which is recommended over `SnapToDevicePixels`), but in this case it still leaves a line between elements.

Comment: why is UseLayoutRounding recommended over SnapToDevicePixels?

Comment: @3xGuy Historically for compatibility, because `UseLayoutRounding` is also available on [Silverlight](https://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/) (which was discontinued). Other than that, `UseLayoutRounding` aligns boundaries in the layout phase, while `SnapToDevicePixels` works during the render phase. Both have their advantages and disadvantages and the effect is different.